# I want a like button that contains custom parameters, how can I do that?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I want to insert a facebook like button to my page: `<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.site.com/news/b_news.php" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

I want to pass custom parameters for every single article I have. For example, I have `index.php?function=news&id=33`, and whenever I like the article with the ID 33, I want that article's title and image to be the liked page's image and title appearing on Facebook. I know about these meta tags, but those are for static pages, since I've got only one  in my website and the meta tags should look like this: `<meta content="'.$new['id'].'" property="og:description"></meta>` where I'm fetching the description data from an array, from database. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just set meta tags dynamically (pseudo-code below):

```php
// Controller

// Default values
$view->meta_title = 'Hello';
$view->meta_image = 'http://image';

$article = Model_Article($id)

if ($article->loaded()) {
    $view->meta_title = $article->title
    $view->meta_image = $article->image_url();
}
// View
<html>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $meta_title ?>">
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $meta_image ?>">
    <!--.......-->
```